# Problemas con Threading y bucles

Tags: java, condiciones, hilos

Estoy realizando un programa que simula una carrera usando Thread en Java en la que tengo una liebre y una tortuga. Ambos empiezan en la misma posicion y segun un numero aleatorio realizan alguna de las acciones que tienen (probabilidades de avanzar o regresar x casillas). El problema es que no entiendo porque en el final de un bucle if else algunas veces entra en el "else" ya que puse adecuadamente las condiciones y el valor del numero aleatorio esta entre 0 y 100 comprobado de manera aparte. Adjunto el codigo de liebre y el main con la carrera (a la clase tortuga le pasa lo mismo):

```
import java.util.Random;

class Liebre extends Thread {

private int posicion = 0;
private volatile int ganador = -1; 
private Object lock = new Object();

public void run() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    while (posicion < 70 && ganador == -1) {
        synchronized(lock){
            int numAleatorio2 = rand.nextInt(101); 
            
            if(numAleatorio2 >= 0 && 20 <= numAleatorio2) {
                posicion +=3;
            }
            else if(numAleatorio2 >= 21 && 40 <= numAleatorio2) {
                posicion +=9;
            }
            else if(numAleatorio2 >= 41 && 50 <= numAleatorio2) {
                if((posicion - 12) <= 1)
                    posicion = 1;
                else
                    posicion -=12;
            }
            else if(numAleatorio2 >= 51 && 80 <= numAleatorio2) {
                posicion +=1;
            }
            else if(numAleatorio2 >= 81 && 100 <= numAleatorio2) {
                if((posicion - 2) <= 1)
                    posicion = 1;
                else
                    posicion -=2;
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Error liebre");
                
            System.out.println("Posicion Liebre: " + posicion);
            if(posicion >= 70){
                ganador = 0;
                System.out.println("Liebre ha ganado la carrera!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(250);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Y el metodo carrera

```
public class Carrera {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Liebre liebre = new Liebre();
    Tortuga tortuga = new Tortuga();
    liebre.start();
    tortuga.start();
}
```

}

Comment: empieza por separar todo eso en métodos y no matar toda la JVM desde un hilo (Sí, eso hace System.exit)

Comment: A que te refieres con lo del System.exit? Estoy sobrecargando la JVM? No deberia saltar algun error?

Comment: System.exit mata (termina) el proceso y, por tanto, todos los hilos que formen parte del mismo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El sutil error está en la propia condición de los **if**, la forma correcta es la siguiente:

```
int numAleatorio2 = rand.nextInt( 101 );

if( numAleatorio2 < 2 ) {
   posicion += 3;
}
else if( numAleatorio2 < 41 ) {
   posicion += 9;
}
else if( numAleatorio2 < 51 ) {
   if( ( posicion - 12 ) <= 1 ) {
      posicion = 1;
   }
   else {
      posicion -= 12;
   }
}
else if( numAleatorio2 < 81 ) {
   posicion += 1;
}
else if( numAleatorio2 < 101 ) {
   if( ( posicion - 2 ) <= 1 ) {
      posicion = 1;
   }
   else {
      posicion -= 2;
   }
}
else {
   System.out.println( "Error liebre " + numAleatorio2 );
}
```

Porque tu código falla, porque usas

```
numAleatorio2 >= 0 && 20 <= numAleatorio2
```

en lugar de

```
numAleatorio2 >= 0 &&  numAleatorio2 <= 20
```

por ejemplo, cuando ingresas 19, es mayor que cero... pero 20 **no** es menor ni igual que 19, sutil, pero fatídico.

Comment: Efectivamente, el orden de los factores en una comprobación de rangos importa :) Por querer hacerlo más "atractivo" visualmente se introdujo un bug en la funcionalidad. La consistencia es importante en programación, si comparas primero tu variable y luego un número -> `numAleatorio >= 1` por ejemplo... hazlo siempre igual. Te evitas tener que pensar de dos maneras diferentes constantemente, y por ende te evitas estos errores tontos.